# Updating HBase data with HappyBase

Tags: python, hbase, happybase

I am trying to write a function to update Data from a table saved in HBase. I have a function that will get called to Update it and I have a pretty good start but I am a little bit lost on the end of finishing it. I can update single rows based one string to another, but when comparing log times, I can not seem to figure out how to do that, since there are no set log times. I am storing all of values from the table into a dictionary. Here is my code:

```
def updateHBase(row):

dict = row.asDict() #create a dictionary from Row

columns = dict.keys()
    for col in columns: #creates the colfamily:colname for happybase format
        dict["DriveInfo:" +col] = dict.pop(col) #adds data into rows

del dict[DriveInfo:serialnumb] #removes the row key that HBase uses, serialnum

x = table.row(row.serialnum) 

if (len(x) == 0) #length of row is zero, row key does not exist
    table.put(row.serialnum, dict) #add new row is row key does not exist

else #check for health
    if (dict['health'].lower() != 'healthy') #if the row isnt healthy... next steps

        if (dict['health'].lower() != 'archived' and x['health'] == 'archived' and dict['logtime'] < x['logtime']) #update a row with a health status of archived
            table.put(row.serialnum, dict) 

        else #if the row that is being replaced isn't archived, just replace the row
            table.put(row.serialnum, dict) 
        return

    elif (dict['logtime'] > x['logtime'] and dict['health'].lower() == 'healthy') # new log time > old log time and health is healthy, replace the row with new data
        table.put(row.serialnum, dict)

    else
        return
```

EDIT: In all of my if statements should ... `dict['health']` ... be `x['health']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
def updateHBase(row):

dict = row.asDict() #create a dictionary from Row

columns = dict.keys()
    for col in columns: #creates the colfamily:colname for happybase format
        dict["DriveInfo:" +col] = dict.pop(col) #adds data into rows

del dict[DriveInfo:serialnumb] #removes the row key that HBase uses, serialnum

x = table.row(row.serialnum) 

if (len(x) == 0) #length of row is zero, row key does not exist
    table.put(row.serialnum, dict) #add new row is row key does not exist

else #check for health
    if (x['health'].lower() != 'healthy') #if the row isnt healthy... next steps

        if (x['health'].lower() != 'archived' and x['health'] == 'archived') #update a row with a health status of archived
            table.put(row.serialnum, dict) 

        else #if the row that is being replaced isn't archived, just replace the row
            table.put(row.serialnum, dict) 
        return

    elif (x['logtime'] > row.logtime and x['health'].lower() == 'healthy') # new log time > old log time and health is healthy, replace the row with new data
        table.put(row.serialnum, dict)

    else
        return
```